# Engagement Pictures

Tags: minhag, tznius-modesty, wedding, engagement-shidduch, chassan-groom

I have heard in the past that there is a custom that the Chosson and Kallah should not pose for pictures together until they are married. This includes the engagement party and any other occasion.

Is there a source for this in Halacha or Minhag? Or is this just a recent custom amongst certain communities?

Comment: Photography is only 150 years old, so any such custom is bound to be pretty recent as Judaism goes.

Comment: There are many halachic works as well as sefarim on Minhag written in the past 150 years

Comment: It would have been more strict before photography, where they would have had to pose for a painting.

Comment: Reportedly, Reb Dovid Feinstein would encourage the bride and groom to take pictures together before the chupa, rather than not see each other before the chupa and make all the guests wait will they take pictures after the chupa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a book about Lubavitcher customs, etc. regarding shidduchim and marriage, [Eternal Joy, volume 2.](https://www.sichos-in-english.org/books/eternal-joy-2/06.htm)

> Rabbi Leibel Groner relates that the Rebbe also asked him to publicize his displeasure with the following:
> It recently has become endemic that chassan and kallah come together after their engagement party for pictures. Moreover, they even take photographs together in a photo studio.
>
> The Rebbe once told an individual during a private Yechidus:
>
> In heaven they are ashamed of the fact ... that chassan and kallah are photographed together before their wedding.

Comment: "The Rebbe once told an individual during a private Yechidus: In heaven they are ashamed of the fact ... that chassan and kallah are photographed together before their wedding." Where do you see that something told to an individual with a specific and unstated context should be broadly applicable? What evidence is there that this privately communicated statement has now risen to the level of custom?

Comment: @Deuteronomy “ Rabbi Leibel Groner relates that the Rebbe also asked him to publicize his displeasure with the following:”

Comment: So you report that he expressed displeasure "that chassan and kallah come together *after their engagement party* for pictures." This does not say anything about his opinion of pictures before the engagement party (at time of engagement, at לחיים, etc.), nor an opinion about pictures at the engagement party, nor about during the engagement period generally. It also doesn't specify by what is meant by "come together". IMHO it simply doesn't answer the question of MINHAG/HALAKHA which was asked about. Is there now an accepted minhag in that community? All that is documented here is "displeasure"